# Cannot return properly View with prefix and parameter

Tags: laravel, view

I have an route that looks as following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'show' ], function() {

    Route::get('{id}', function($id)
    {
        return View::make('show')->with('id' , $id);
    });

});
```

When I enter URL etc `test.com/show/343242` it returns what it should. But what I want it to redirect to that site. When I use `Redirect::to('show/34324');` it simply just give me an blank screen. When I try to use `return Redirect::route('show/34324');` it just give me that the route `show/34324` don't exist. I have no idea how to proceed, have search around for 1 hour until now.

Hopefully someone can bring some light into this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should return your [Redirect](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects)

```php
return Redirect::to('show/34324');
```

To Redirect from a named route

```php
Route::get('{id}', array('as'=>'route-name',function($id)
{
    return View::make('show')->with('id' , $id);
}));
// ...
return Redirect::route('route-name',array(34324));
```